# Как выйти из click в javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

Есть такой код

```
$("button[name='publish']").click(function() {
    $(this).blur();

    var id = $(this).attr("data-article-id");
    var button = $(this);

    $.ajax({
        url: '/public/php/setPublish.php',
        type: "POST",
        data: {id : id, publish : 1},
        success: function() {
            $(button).attr("name", "not-publish");
            $(button).removeClass("btn-success");
            $(button).addClass("btn-danger");
            $(button).text("Not publish");

            return;
        }
    });
});

$("button[name='not-publish']").click(function() {
    $(this).blur();

    var id = $(this).attr("data-article-id");
    var button = $(this);

    $.ajax({
        url: '/public/php/setPublish.php',
        type: "POST",
        data: {id : id, publish : 0},
        success: function() {
            $(button).attr("name", "publish");
            $(button).removeClass("btn-danger");
            $(button).addClass("btn-success");
            $(button).text("Publish");

            return;
        }
    });
});
```

После того как я нажал на одну кнопку я меняю ей название и несколько классов. Потом если я хочу нажать на эту новую кнопку, то обработчик остается на старой кнопке. Что делать?

Comment: очевиден неверный подход. выражение _я меняю ее на другую_ - неверно. Кнопка как была, так и осталась, и все обработчики остались на ней

Comment: Попробуйте воспользоваться unbind.